# Name of anime where kids train to be goddess pilots

Tags: story-identification, space, anime, mecha

Eventually one does and syncs with it and gets a partner that acts as an engineer for the suit and then he and his team of goddesses go up in space and fight monsters that regularly attack Earth. The kid was never supposed to get in the goddess but eventually gets sucked into the cockpit and syncs with the goddess. He has a special ability that makes him super fast and strong for a bit and makes his hair white.

Comment: Did the goddesses look like people? Inhuman? Giant robots?

Comment: @fuzzyboots yes thank You! Pilot Candidate! I loved this anime when it came out on toonami/adult swim a decade ago. I was sad they didn't make more episodes. This could have evolved into a truly good anime. The concept was good and original at the time. I loved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [*Megami Kouhosei*](https://myanimelist.net/anime/888/Megami_Kouhosei) (AKA *Pilot Candidate*).

> In the future humankind has expanded and colonized other planets. Then
>   an alien species, Victim, attacks the human colonies leaving only one
>   planet, Zion. In an effort to stop Victim from destroying the last
>   planet a training school, **GOA, is set up to gather boys from the Zion
>   colonies and train them to become pilots of the Ingrids AKA The
>   Goddesses, five fighting robots that protect Zion.** The boys must
>   possess a rare blood type, EO, as well as a special ability, or EX.
>   Zero (Candidate 88) has just arrived in GOA when he falls into the
>   cockpit of the Ingrid Eeva-Leena. Since the synch between pilot and
>   Ingrid are very sensitive everyone believes the Goddess will kill Zero
>   in an attempt to synch. Just before Zero passes out he makes a full
>   synch with the Goddess. Before he can find out more about the
>   incident, his pilot training begins.

Comment: Ah yes, the much maligned *Pilot Candidate* (as it was called in the US release)

Comment: @Machavity - I've never seen it, but it sounds a lot like 'budget Evangelion'

Comment: More like "Evangelion, but with 50% less plot"